# in powerapps how do I get a collection of the selected values of a multiselect from a sharepoint list WITHOUT using a combobox

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, sharepoint-list, powerapps-collection

I have a sharepoint list that has a multiselect column.
in powerapps I would like to make a collection of the selected values.

for example I have a  multiselect column named category that have choices One, Two, Three, and Four.
I have selected Two and Four.

my code in powerapps Integrated Form OnEdit is

```
Clear(myCollection); 
ForAll(Choices([@SMEList].Category), Collect(myCollection,ThisRecord.Value));
```

but that is giving me One, Two, Three and Four.
I only want the selected Values (Two and Four)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This works:**

```
ClearCollect(colMyCollection,
    Filter(
        Choices('2022-05-23_StackOverflow'.SMEList),
        Or(
            ThisRecord.Value = "Choice 2",
            ThisRecord.Value = "Choice 4"
        )
    )
)
```

**Illustrated:**

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

- Ok. I changed the SP column to multiselect.
- `OnStart` of the app, `ClearCollect(colList, <SP_list_name>)`
- Insert a Gallery control, set its `Items` property to `colList`. Set its `OnSelect` property to `Set(varRecord, ThisItem)`
- Insert a Form control, set its `Item` property to `LookUp(colList, ID = varRecord.ID)`

**Illustrated**

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

**RE:** `...just get it from the sharepoint list .`

- **Leave** the `OnStart` function to `ClearCollect(colList, SharepointList)`
- Gallery:

  - **Leave** the Gallery`Items` property to `colList`
  - **Change** the TextBox (in the Gallery) `Text` property to `Concat(ThisItem.SMEList, Value, ",")`
- Form:

  - You already have the values from the Sharepoint list in the ComboBox. Its unclear to me why you to manipulate these values *outside* of the ComboBox.
  - How about just changing the `DisplayMode` property of the ComboBox to `View`.
  - Then its read-only

[image]

Comment: sorry I am a bit confused this looks like you do  not have a multi select for your choices.   my column is a multiselect of choices (one row can have more than one choice.)   so  for row 1 say I pick Choice 1 and Choice 4.   for row 2 I pick Choice 2 and Choice 3.   In the Power App Integrated form for Row 1 I want the collection to be Choice 1 and Choice 4 and for row 2 in the Power App Integrated form I want the collection to contain Choice 2 and Choice 3 (Nothing should be hardcoded)

Comment: Please see edit 1

Comment: thanks actually that is the solution I am currently using but I was hoping to do it without having to have a combobox. and just get it from the sharepoint list but I don't think it is possible.  I don't think you can get the selected values directly from the sharepoint list.

Comment: Please see edit 2

Comment: thanks  I am using a hidden combobox and a collection to populate checkboxes.  I would love to not have to use the combobox (I am using checkboxes instead and I don't want or need a combobox)  I was just wondering if it is possible to get the selected values into a collection  directly from the sharepoint list WITHOUT  having to use any kind of control (combobox, textarea etc.)  like Filter(Choices([@SMEList].Category,selected) which I know isn't a thing.

Comment: `colList.SMEList` **IS** `...the selected values into a collection directly from the sharepoint list...` Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `[@SMEList].Category` indicates you have a Lookup column of "Category" on "SMEList".

You say you want a collection without using a combo box? Yet, you only want the selected values, so where are these getting selected, if not from a box? Even if you don't want the user to mess with the box, you can set it to disabled, view or visible = false. So I'm going to include that route and then also talk about getting the values from the list, directly.

**Combo Box**

```
Concat(ComboBox1.SelectedItems,Value,",")
```

or it might be:

```
Concat(ComboBox1.SelectedItems,Category,",")
```

This would let you pull all selected values together. So it would go:

```
Collect(myCollection,Concat(ComboBox1.SelectedItems,Value,","));
Collect(myCollection,Concat(ComboBox1.SelectedItems,Category,","));
```

Or, using the `OnChange` of the combo box:

```
ClearCollect( myCollection, ComboBox1.SelectedItems );
```

Automatically updating the collection whenever any selected items are changed.

(And in the App's OnStart, do `Set(myCollection, [])` as you probably already have.)

**Without a combo box**

You could also set the list into a collection from the beginning, in the App's OnStart, like:

```
Set(colList, []);
ClearCollect(colList, [@SMEList])
```

...and based on an ID, you call to that collection to get its values, like SeaDude demonstrated using a gallery and then he set a combo box using the result, basically the key was: `LookUp(colList, ID = varRecord.ID)`

Where `varRecord` was set to `ThisItem` from the list:

Gallery's OnSelect property: `Set(varRecord, ThisItem)`

...So it sets the item that the gallery was invoking. (And then he set that item equal to the combo box's `Items` property using that `LookUp` formula, above.)

But that code takes the collection with the list in it and lets you send in an ID and get the whole item, with all of its columns, back out. You can do a lot with a `LookUp` command just on its own if you are going against a list directly, and without an ID, too:

`ClearCollect(myCollection,LookUp([@SMEList],'Created'<Today()).'Category')`

...could potentially grab you every `Category` value on that `SMEList` that was Created before today. You can use any condition you want (ID equals something, Title equals something, etc.).

**Either direction**

After you get your collection, you can do a `CountRows` on your `myCollection` to see how many values it has to see if it matches what you expect:

```
Notify(CountRows(myCollection), NotificationType.Information)
```